# Avoid repetitive try/except in python

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-decorators

I have several functions (`f`, `g`, `o`) that have `arg1` as input.

`arg1` is positif, mandatory and located in different position:

```
def f(a, b, arg1):
    print(arg1)

def g(c, arg1):
    print(arg1)

def o(arg1, d, 2):
    print(arg1)
```

In case `arg1` is negatif I raise an exception:

```
def is_positif(a):
    if a < 0:
        raise ValueError('arg1 should be positif)
```

To avoid repeat the `try/except` statements on all functions:

```
def f(a, b, arg1):
    try:
        is_positif(arg1)
        print(arg1)
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
```

I investigated the idea of creating a decorator.

```
from functools import wraps

def valid_arg(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            is_positif(kwargs['arg1'])
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
    return wrapper

def is_positif(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError("arg1 should be positif")

@valid_arg
def f(a, b, arg1):
    print(arg1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f(1, 2, arg1=3)
```

However, this solution force me to use `arg1` as a keyword argument (`arg1=3`) and seems overkilling.

I have noticed a few response in previous post with the usage of the `contextmanager`.

However, the `contextmanager` from what I read will re-raise the exception so it does not solve my problem.

Could you please tell me what is the righ approach ?

Regards,

Comment: In your example you print the error then continue as if nothing happened, is this the correct design?  If all you are doing is printing the error (which should probably go to `stderr` rather than `stdout`) , then why trap it at all?  Would using `assert` be more appropriate?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you try to solve? Holding arg1 positive raise exception otherwise?

Comment: What about a decorator with arguments?

Comment: The code provided is simplified for what I am actually doing.  

The real code is a script that does some computation and in case of exception it exists and return a  usefull error message to the User  (cf `print(err)`).
I trap it (`try/except`) because I do not want to have a trace as error message. 

(I should consider using stderr instead of stdout)

Comment: Not really understand the downgrade for a question looking for advice.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeat the try/except statements on all functions you can just wrap your "useful" code into a single try-catch, and print useful error message in it. Also, you can create custom exception for your case.

```
# Your custom exception
class NegativeArg1(Exception):
    pass

# Your checker
def check_positive(arg1):
    if val < 0:
        raise NegativeArg1("Your arg1 is negative!")

# Your calculation function
def f1(a, b, arg1):
    check_positive(arg1)
    # make calculations...
    c = a + b
    return c

# Your other calculation function
def f2(a, b, arg1, d, e):
    check_positive(arg1)
    # make calculations...
    c = a + b - d - e
    return c

# Your main code block:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:        
        r1 = f1(1, 2, arg1=3)
        r2 = f2(1, 2, arg1=-5, 6, 7)

    except NegativeArg1 as n:
        print("Oh on! You've speecified negative arg1 somethere!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Some other exception has happened:" + str(e))
```